# Create publisher extension that can be executed on every event

Tags: swift, combine

I'm having hard time learning combine.

What I try to reach is to create some helper for `mockedLoader` that will fail from time to time.

I wrote such extension:

```
struct AnyError: Error {}

extension Publisher where Failure == Error {
    func fail(withProbability probability: Float, error: Failure = AnyError()) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        let treshold = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
        let p = Int(probability * 100)
        if treshold + p >= 100 {
            return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        return self.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to use it in my Publisher like that:

```
let mockedLoader: AnyPublisher<[TransactionItem], Error> = client.getPublisher(url: URL(string: "https://testing.com")!)
     .subscribe(on: upstreamQueue)
     .fail(withProbability: 0.05)
     .delay(for: .seconds(2), tolerance: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: upstreamQueue)
     .tryMap(TransactionsMapper.map)
     .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

I realized the fail block is executed only once at the beginning when Publisher is created. I would like to have this probability logic called every time there is a event and based on logic return Fail of self publisher.

What I'm doing wrong here. Should I use some operator but which one?

Comment: yes, you need to write an operator. But it would be a lot simpler just to reuse an existing operator such as trymap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to add a `TryMap` operator into the chain instead trying to create a custom Publisher:

First, implement this function:

```
func fail<Value>(
    value: Value, 
    with probability: Float, 
    error: Error
) throws -> Value {
    ...
}
```

Then, in your chain of Combine operators, insert a `tryMap` where the upstream is the value which may also fail:

```
    someOperatorPublishingValue
    .tryMap { value in 
        try fail(value: value, with: 0.1, error: MyError())
    } 
    ...
```

You may choose `Value` to be what suites your needs. In your case, it's likely the output of the `client.getPublisher` publisher.

You may need to adjust for error types in the downstream.